# How to fix Android notification issue?

Tags: java, android, service, notifications

I have a service which needs to write a notification on the status bar when some event occurs

```
package com.octoplus.client.services;

import android.app.Notification;
import android.app.NotificationManager;
import android.app.PendingIntent;
import android.app.Service;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.IBinder;

import com.octoplus.client.MainActivity;
import com.octoplus.client.R;

import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

public class notif extends Service {
    public notif() {
    }
    NotificationManager nm;
    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not yet implemented");
    }
    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        nm = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    }
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {

        sendNotif();
        return super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);
    }

    void sendNotif() {
        // 1-я часть
        Notification notif = new Notification(R.drawable.ic_launcher, "We create gif", System.currentTimeMillis());
        // ставим флаг, чтобы уведомление пропало после нажатия
        notif.flags |= Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;
        // отправляем
        nm.notify(1, notif);
/*
        // 3-я часть
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
       // intent.putExtra(MainActivity.FILE_NAME, "somefile");
        PendingIntent pIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, intent, 0);

        // 2-я часть
        notif.setLatestEventInfo(this, "Notification's title", "Notification's text", pIntent);
*/


    }

}
```

I call it with use this code

```
startService(new Intent(MainActivity.this, notif.class));
```

but I made some mistake and I always get this exception

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start service com.octoplus.client.services.notif@5334d2c8 with Intent { cmp=com.octoplus.client/.services.notif }: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: contentView required: pkg=com.octoplus.client id=1 notification=Notification(pri=0 contentView=null vibrate=null sound=null defaults=0x0 flags=0x10 kind=[null])
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleServiceArgs(ActivityThread.java:2721)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1900(ActivityThread.java:141)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1353)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5103)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:737)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: contentView required: pkg=com.octoplus.client id=1 notification=Notification(pri=0 contentView=null vibrate=null sound=null defaults=0x0 flags=0x10 kind=[null])
    at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1435)
    at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1385)
    at android.app.INotificationManager$Stub$Proxy.enqueueNotificationWithTag(INotificationManager.java:320)
    at android.app.NotificationManager.notify(NotificationManager.java:136)
    at android.app.NotificationManager.notify(NotificationManager.java:109)
    at com.octoplus.client.services.notif.sendNotif(notif.java:41)
    at com.octoplus.client.services.notif.onStartCommand(notif.java:31)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleServiceArgs(ActivityThread.java:2704)
    ... 10 more
```

How I can fix it?

Comment: where are you calling this startService(new Intent(MainActivity.this, notif.class));

Comment: from other activity activity

Comment: have you declared this service in manifest file?

Comment: I fix it 
        NotificationManager manager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

        Notification notification = new Notification(R.drawable.ic_launcher,
                "Hello from service", System.currentTimeMillis());

        Intent intent = new Intent(this, tab_1_Activity.class);

        notification.setLatestEventInfo(this, "Condtats", "Your GIF and video was prepared...",
                PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 1, intent, 0));
        manager.notify(111, notification);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

found that you are not calling Notification.setLatestEventInfo(). this might cause crash try uncommenting it